# zsh function for shrinking $PWD with $HOME replacement

Tags: strings, shell, zsh

I wanted a `$PWD` shrinking for my `$PROMPT` with the following requirements:

- `$HOME` is replaced by ~
- All subpaths except the last one are replaced by their initial letters
- Reasonably efficient

This is my attempt, with tests:

```
#!/bin/zsh

function shrinkpath()
{
  local dir="${1/#$HOME/~}"
  if [ $dir = "~" ]; then
    echo "~"
    return
  fi
  local split=(${(s:/:)dir%/*})
  local prefix="/"
  if [ "$split[1]" = "~" ]; then
    prefix=""
  fi
  local mid=$(for i ("$split[@]") ; do echo -n "${i:0:1}/" ; done)
  local last="${dir##*/}"
  echo "$prefix$mid$last"
}

echo "$(shrinkpath $HOME)"
echo "$(shrinkpath $HOME/foo)"
echo "$(shrinkpath $HOME/foo/bar/baz)"
echo "$(shrinkpath /)"
echo "$(shrinkpath /foo)"
echo "$(shrinkpath /foo/bar/baz)"
```

Output:

```
~
~/foo
~/f/b/baz
/
/foo
/f/b/baz
```

Seems to be doing the trick but I feel it could be smaller/simpler. In particular, my intuition tells me that I should be able to get away with a single check for `"~"` instead of two, and that I might be using too many intermediate variables. I am also not sure about whether there is a better way to do the "split by / and get the first letter of each subpath" part.

Answer (score 3):

As this is for a prompt:

```
shrinkpath () {
  local split dir=${PWD/#~\//\~/}
  case $dir in
    ~) dir='~' ;;
    *) split=( "${(@s:/:)dir}" )
       dir=${(j:/:M)split#?}${split[-1]:1} ;;
  esac
  psvar[1]=$dir
}

precmd_functions=( shrinkpath )
PS1='%1v%# '
```

This is similar to your current approach (split->process->join). The `#` modifier combined with the `(M)` flag is used for removing everything except the first character in every path component (after HOME prefix replacement). The last component is appended with its first character removed.

A `prefix` variable is not needed as the `s` flag is used inside double quotes with the `@` flag (`man zshexpn` says of `s:string:` "*For historical reasons, the usual behaviour that empty array elements are retained inside double quotes is disabled for arrays generated by splitting*" ... "*To override this behaviour, supply the `(@)` flag as well*").

`psvar` is an array to use with the `%v` sequence in the prompt string. For testing, I added `print -r -- $dir` to the end of `shrinkpath()` so that different PWDs can be passed to see what it does with them (note the fourth test where HOME appears as a prefix, but isn't the user's home):

```
% PWD=$HOME shrinkpath
~
% PWD=$HOME/foo shrinkpath
~/foo
% PWD=$HOME/foo/bar/baz shrinkpath
~/f/b/baz
% PWD=${HOME}foo/bar/baz shrinkpath
/h/x/b/baz
% PWD=/ shrinkpath
/
% PWD=/foo shrinkpath
/foo
% PWD=/foo/bar/baz shrinkpath
/f/b/baz
```

Using `%v` in the prompt string and making use of a function to alter the `psvar` array should be more efficient than using the `PROMPT_SUBST` option with `$(shrinkpath)` as that approach would fork a subshell.

The `*` case could be changed to:

```
    */*/*)
       dir="${(@j:/:M)${(@s:/:)dir}#?}${dir##*/(?|)}" ;;
```

`*/*/*` to skip the split/join process when it's not needed. Zsh can nest parameter expansions like `${${${var}}}`, so the intermediate `split` array is not really needed.